Getting 400 error while trying to submit AJAX form in WordPress
I created a signup form in WordPress and try to submit the form using AJAX and handling by the class Custom Form. But it responds 400 bad request as capture:

Codes enclosed:
HTML Template
get_header();
?>
<div class="authn main-content">
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <form id="authn">
        <div class="form">
            <!-- Prefix -->
            <label for="prefix">Title</label>
            <div class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="prefix" value="mr" checked>
                <label for="mr">Mr.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="prefix" value="ms">
                <label for="ms">Ms.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="prefix" value="mrs">
                <label for="mrs">Mrs.</label>
            </div>

            <!-- First Name -->
            <label for="fname">First Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="fname">

            <!-- Last Name -->
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="lname">

            <!-- Email -->
            <label for="email">Email</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    
            <!-- Password -->
            <div class="password">
                <label for="password">Password</label><br>
                <input type="password" name="password">
                <i class="icon bi bi-eye-slash eye"></i>
            </div>

            <!-- Confirm Password -->
            <div class="password">
                <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label><br>
                <input type="password" name="confirm-password">
                <i class="icon bi bi-eye-slash eye"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="terms">
            <!-- Terms -->
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="terms">
                <span class="term">I agree to the <a class="text-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url() . '/terms-of-use'; ?>">terms</a> and the <a class="text-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url() . '/privacy-policy'; ?>">privacy policy</a>.</span>
            </div>

            <p>Already have had an account? <a class="text-link" href="<?php echo get_site_url() . '/login'; ?>">Login</a>.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();

Class for registering scripts that is surely implemented.
`<?php
class Register_Scripts_Style {
    // Prevent from multiple instantiations
    use Singleton;

    // The __construct function is set to private since it is not allowed to instantiate in in public.
    private function __construct() {
        // Actions
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'register_stylesheet']);
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'register_javascript']);
    }

    // Register and enqueue stylesheets
    public function register_stylesheet() {
        // Unrelated code
    }   

    public function register_javascript() {
        // Get the current page slug's that is mainly for login and signup page)
        $slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post());

        // Register script
        wp_register_script('bookstore-jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js', array(), '3.7.1', false); // Jquery
        wp_register_script('bookstore-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);// main.js

        // Enqueue Scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('bookstore-jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('bookstore-main');

        // Only register authn.js in login and signup page
        if ($slug === 'login' || $slug === 'signup'):
            wp_register_script('bookstore-authn', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/authn.js', array('bookstore-main'), '1.0.0', true);// authn.js

            // it allows to pass PHP-generated data to JQuery.
            // 'ajax_url' will be the URL for the WP AJAX endpoint, which allows to make AJAX requests to the WP backend (admin-ajax.php).
            wp_localize_script( 'bookstore-authn', 'bookstore_authn',
            array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
            
            wp_enqueue_script('bookstore-authn');
        endif;
    }
}`

Class for sending data to db, however at the moment I just want to echo the input value to the page for testing.
class Custom_Form {
    // Prevent from multiple instantiations
    use Singleton;

    // The __construct function is set to private since it is not allowed to instantiate in in public.
    private function __construct() {
        // Actions
        add_action('wp_ajax_signup_form_submit', [$this, 'signup_form_submit']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_form_submission', [$this, 'signup_form_submit']);
    }

    // Submit signup form
    public static function signup_form_submit() {
        echo $_POST['prefix'];
    }
}

AJAX for handling the form data.
$(document).ready(() => {
    // Submit form
    $('#authn').submit((function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const form = $(this);
        const formData = {
            prefix: form.find('input[name="prefix"]:checked').val()
        };
        
        // Fire off the request to the /admin-ajax.php
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: bookstore_authn.ajax_url, // // This is the URL for the WordPress AJAX endpoint from Register_Script_Style class 
            data: {
                action: 'signup_form_submit',
                data: formData
            },
            success: res => {
                console.log('res: ' + res);
            },
            error: err => {
                console.log('err: ' + err);
            }
        })
    }));
}); 

Thank you so much!!
I want to figure out what are the issues that causes the 400 response, thank you so much!

If the problem occurs while you are not logged in, try to replace the action hook
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_form_submission', [$this, 'signup_form_submit']);

to
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_signup_form_submit', [$this, 'signup_form_submit']);

Note: wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action} Fires non-authenticated Ajax actions for logged-out users. For more detail, click
